# Retrieve data from SQL table using PHP or AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

Simple question: I can retrieve my data from my database using the following at the top of my page:

```
    ....
    $query = "SELECT * FROM first_page_data WHERE email_address='$user' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $first_data);
    $row_details = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

and then reference to the data using $row_details. Or I can use AJAX. What are the main pros and cons of using either? Im happy to change to using AJAX and would like to learn it at some point, but Id like to think there are advantages to using it rather than the PHP method shown.

Comment: Even with AJAX, you are required to use code above

Comment: Ah! maybe I shouldve looked into it a bit more before asking the question! So if the data has already been retrieved using PHP then what is the point in AJAX?

Comment: AJAX can be used if for example the user does some input on the site and you want to change the shown details based on his input without reloading the data (like the instant-search on google). Via AJAX, you request the data from the php-script and use it in JavaScript to display the data, but the php-script still uses the same code to query in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The short answer**

It depends on the situation.

**The long answer**

If there is really no need to use AJAX (other than user convenience) the way you do it would be the right way to go. But either way, the same code you posted applies for both AJAX and non-AJAX ways. There is no other benefit of using AJAX other than allowing users to perform certain actions without refreshing the page (which is the sole premise of AJAX).

Comment: I dont quite understand yet - if the PHP code stays as it is, the returned data from the database must always be the same, then what can AJAX do with that data that Javascript cant?

Comment: Usually, when you click the form's submit button, the page refreshes as the data gets passed through. AJAX turns this into a background process, so that the page doesn't have to refresh.

Answer (score 1):

**index.php**

```
<input type="text" name="username" >
<input type="text" name="password" >
<script>
var = {
"name": $("input[name=username]").val(),
"pass": $("input[name=password]").val()
}
$.post("yourPHP.php",{var_holder:var},function(data){
alert(data); // this is where your php output
});
</script>
```

**yourphp.php**

```
<?php
echo "OK";
/*

this is where your query happens...
 ....
    $query = "SELECT * FROM first_page_data WHERE email_address='$user' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $first_data);
    $row_details = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

*/
?>
```

this is the basic ajax code, hope it helps.